# Disable home button and recent apps button in android application

Tags: android

I need to disable home button and recent apps button in my application since the activity opened which takes information is required and cannot leave empty

Comment: You cannot disable parts of the system UI, how would the user exit your app?

Comment: AFAIK, not possible. You can, however, detect the keys pressed but not prevent the default system operation. Easy solution - hide the bottom navigation bar but bad UX.

Comment: Look into kiosk mode.

Answer (score 0):

You can look for kiosk mode but that will require special permission (device admin permission) to activate.

you can also try "startLockTask()" in activity onCreate that will create a pinned screen